# if my input is 3 get it says it is not prime number

Tags: c

```
this find out whether the given number is prime or not
```

whats wrong with this code,it says that the number 3 is not prime number
the number 3 is prime number then whats wrong with this
if i took number 2 as a input then also its wrong

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    void main()
    {
        int num,i,j,inum,flag=0;
        printf("\n Enter the number :");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        inum=sqrt(num);
        for(i=2;i<inum;i++)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag=1;
            }

        }
        if(flag)
        {
            printf("\n TThe number %d is prime",num);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n The number %d is not prime",num);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the debugger say? Did you single-step your code? If not: this is a good time to learn using the debugger.

Comment: if the integer part of the square root of `num` is less or equal to 2, your `for` loop never runs... in that case, what's `flag`?

Comment: `inum=sqrt(2);` --> `inum` is `1`. `inum=sqrt(3);` --> `inum` is `1`.

Comment: @Akshay : Instead of asking this, you should be the one trying to figure out what's wrong with the code. Then only you will learn.

To answer you, `sqrt(3) is 1` and hence the loop never runs. So by your code's logic, 3 is not prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your for loop should be changed to

`for(i=2;i<=inum;i++)`

a cleaner and better code.

```
bool found = true;
for (i=2; i<=inum && found; ++i ) {
    if ( num%i == 0 ) found = false;
}

if ( found ) printf("Prime Number");
else printf("Not Prime");
```

Comment: glad to help @Akshay

Answer (score 0):

In this line `int num,i,j,inum,flag=0;` you need to do `int num,i,j,inum,flag=1;`. Ok now think what happen for this change. I think that now your code don't give the wrong output.

Update: Just think if there have no number in range `sqrt(N)` which able to divide `N` where `(N % thatNumber == 0)` then it's a prime. So flag should be 1 cause, the initial time i consider it's a prime. If it's not a prime then there have a number in range `sqrt(N)` which able to divide `N` where `(N % thatNumber == 0)` and for this cause flag change by 0.